# Query working in PhpMyAdmin but not in Dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

I have a query that displays all the data correctly in PHPMYAdmin but when I test it in Dreamweaver recordset it doesn't display the correct data in the correct columns.
Have anyone have experienced something like this and know what the problem could be? The SQL query is:

```
 select
    *
from
    patient
left join
    person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient
left join
    vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.patv = patient.Patient
left join
    hoger_implantat on hoger_implantat.path = patient.Patient
left join
    vanster_operationer on vanster_operationer.Patientov = patient.Patient
left join
    hoger_operationer on hoger_operationer.Patientoh = patient.Patient
left join
    vanster_processorpatient on vanster_processorpatient.Patientv = patient.Patient
left join
    hoger_processorpatient on hoger_processorpatient.Patienth = patient.Patient;
```

I'm using the recordset and this is the code it generates:

```
   mysql_select_db($database_Audiologiska, $Audiologiska);
$query_ResultTable = "select * from patient left join     person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient left join     vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.patv = patient.Patient left join     hoger_implantat on hoger_implantat.path = patient.Patient left join     vanster_operationer on vanster_operationer.Patientov = patient.Patient left join     hoger_operationer on hoger_operationer.Patientoh = patient.Patient left join     vanster_processorpatient on vanster_processorpatient.Patientv = patient.Patient left join     hoger_processorpatient on hoger_processorpatient.Patienth = patient.Patient;";
$ResultTable = mysql_query($query_ResultTable, $Audiologiska) or die(mysql_error());
$row_ResultTable = mysql_fetch_assoc($ResultTable);
$totalRows_ResultTable = mysql_num_rows($ResultTable);
```

Comment: what is your code of testing?

Comment: The above code is the code that I'm testing.. The data is some example data that is in phpMyAdmin

Comment: it is the query you are running but you must have using some code to run it on server, right?

Comment: Ohh yeah..I forgot to mentionthat I'm using the Recordset. I will update my question in a sec

Comment: I does display the table, but the data is wrong.